# Razor: Ho doI set TextAreaFor name?

Tags: textarea, razor

If I do this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.html, New With {.id = "myTextArea", .name = "myTextArea", .style = "width: 100%; height: 100%"})
```

I get this result:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="myTextArea" name="html" rows="2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></textarea>
```

But how can I set the "name" to "myTextAre" instead of "html"?

Thanks all!

Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind - found out I should use @Html.TextArea instead. :)